# Generic relationship many to one or many to many?

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, relational-database

I am facing the following problem:

I want to create a Consequence Model (Aka : Pros and Conts model) that can be associated to different models ([Generic Relationship Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations)) and contains the following info:

```
Consequences : Boolean (Positive or Negative)
Of : Model_Primary_Key
Reason : Text
Author : User_Primary_Key
Users_likes : List<Users>
```

An object (*Of attribute*) can have many consequences but a consequence will only belong to one consequence , so it should be a many to one relationship.

[image: Entity relational diagram]

The problem is that I don't know if the relation between the consequence model and the other models are many to one or many to many.

Usually when you have a one to many , the part that has the many contains a foreign key to the other, but here if i do that the foreign key will be *Author* and *Of* and the set will be the composite primary key , but if I do that here , a user cannot have more than a consequence per object and it should be possible.

So the only solution that I found is to add to consequence an id as primary key , so at the end it works like a many to many relationship , cause at the end is working like an [Associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity).

So at the end in my Entity relational diagram , how i should represent this relationship? As one to many or as many to many?

Comment: When you mentioned "a user cannot have more than consequence per object", do you mean that there can only be one consequence per user, or are you referring to the Object model? Please clarify.

Comment: @user7485741 what I mean is that a user should be able to create several consequences per object , if I don't create a PK for Consequence I have the problem that as the composite primary key will be Author_ID and Object_ID and with that a user won't be able to create more than one consequence cause the composite PK will be repeated, I hope that I have answer to you with that

Answer (score 2):

You could use djangos implicit `AutoField` as primary key and **NOT** add `unique_together` constraints to overcome the hurdle you describe.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class Consequence(models.Model):
    # implicit AutoField
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_positive_consequence = models.BooleanField()
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ConsequenceLike(models.Model):
    # implicit AutoField
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Consequence)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

This way one `User` can create many `Consequence` instances pointing to the same object, because there is no unique constraint.

This gives you a lot of flexibility to filter later:

```
# created by this user
user_instance.consequence_set.all()

# created by this user, filtered by content type
from myapp.models import MyCarModel
user_instance.consequence_set.filter(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyCarModel))

# created by this user, filtered by object instance
my_car = MyCarModel.objects.first()
user_instance.consequence_set.filter(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(my_car.model),
    object_id=my_car.pk)
```

Comment: Just a thought (to myself maybe): if `ConsequenceLike` will not store additional data, it could be replaced by a `ManyToManyField` on the `Consequence` model.

Comment: The example given in the question and this answer seems incomplete to me because there is no reason to use a Generic relationship here. Agree with comment above.